# HTML5 data attribute with jQuery "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Searching Google only gives me examples with jQuery's .data() function.

However, my problem is using the jQuery's "this", as such:

```
$('#opener').live('click', function() {
var x = this.name;
var y = this.title;
```

Which takes the values from `<a style='cursor:pointer' id='opener' name='$x' title='$y'>`, it includes PHP variables, not that important in my question though.

Now, let's say that I want to get away from such a hacky attempt to store extra data in the HTML elements and store it properly in HTML5 by use of the data- attribute. So, the anchor would look something like:

```
<a style='cursor:pointer' id='opener' data-x='$x' data-y='$y'>
```

How would I then be able to use the "this" in jQuery like the above and get it to pick up the data? I've tried doing `this.data('x')` and `this.data('y')` but that doesn't work, and that's all I've found on the subject.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use

```
$(this).data('x')
```

Inside the callback method, `this` references the dom object, but the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method is defined in the jQuery object wrapper for the element. So you need to wrap the dom element with jQuery using `$(this)`.

Comment: @Blender yes If you want to support only html5 data api supported browsers, But for the time being I think it is best to delegate this to jQuery for cross-browser support